# Related to previous question, how can we format string escaped value?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, mustache, elasticsearch-template

Related to the previous question
[How to make _source field dynamic ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581544/how-to-make-source-field-dynamic-in-elasticsearch-search-template)
I was able to make search template _source field dynamic from the front-end, but due to invalid JSON format, I had to make it to string format. which is very hard to read. Is there any way to make it in a readable form? I tried `\` after each new line to make (as suggested in ruby) but could not get it working.

```
"source": "{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":{\"match\":{\"line\":\"{{text}}\"}},\"filter\":{{{#line_no}}\"range\":{\"line_no\":{{{#start}}\"gte\":\"{{start}}\"{{#end}},{{/end}}{{/start}}{{#end}}\"lte\":\"{{end}}\"{{/end}}}}{{/line_no}}}}}}"
```

this is the string query which saved in a YML file.

I tried with ruby multiline string but still giving a parsing error.
I have created a template.yml file and store the template as given below

```
template: |
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "mustache",
        "source": '{'\
            '"_source": {{#toJson}}fields{{/toJson}}'\
        '}'\
    }
}
```

also tried the replace with double quotes and still backtick not helping.

Comment: How about using multi-line strings in Ruby?

Comment: I have updated the question with multi-line example which still failing, please correct me if the implementation was wrong.

Comment: Can you show this in the context of your Ruby code?

Comment: `YML.load_file(file_path)` <= by this i am loading file and getting search template from YML file. Is this enough ?

Comment: Well, it's not yaml format, it's mustache...

Comment: that i know but i created a template.yml file and saved template in that file.

Comment: you can see my updated question, i have mentioned how I have store the template in YML file